# groupBy only gets the first id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship between **departments** and **users** my pivot table is **department_user**. I wanted to select all the `department_name` depending of the user's department using **groupBy** method to merge all the `department_name` into one. See below my statement.

```
$departmentRecipient = DB::table('users')->select('departments.department_name', 'users.id')
    ->join('department_user', 'users.id', '=', 'department_user.user_id')
    ->join('departments', 'department_user.department_id', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->groupBy('departments.department_name')
    ->get();
```

Result using die and dump.

[image: SC]

As you can see here I have an id of **4** under "Department of Engineering". My main problem is it doesn't fetch all the **id** under "Department of Engineering". But in my SQL I have id of **5** not only **4**. How can I solve this problem? Any help would greatly appreciated. Please see result below.

[image: SC2]

Output:

[image: SC3]

This is the output of my list. I wanted to get all the `users` id belongs to the specific option for the user. But if I choose "Department of Engineering" it only gets the id of **4** not **5**. I wanted to get **4** and **5** once.

Controlller:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
  $departmentRecipient = DB::table('departments')->get();
  return view ('document.create')->with('departmentRecipient', $departmentRecipient);
}

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'recipient' => 'required',
    ]);             


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category;

    $document->save();

    $user = Auth::user();


    foreach($request->recipient as $recipientId)
    {
        $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
    }

}
```

Model

**User**

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Department', 'department_user');
}
```

**Department**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\User', 'department_user');
}
```

View

```
<div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "recipient" class = "control-label">Recipient:</label>

        <select name = "recipient[]" multiple class = "form-control select2-multi" id = "myUserList">


            @foreach ($departmentRecipient as $list)
                <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Describing your intended output would help

Comment: You need to describe the problem clearly. It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So when you choose 'Department of Engineering' you want to get a list ['4', '5']? Or you want to get entire row of the user_id 4 and 5 from users table?

Comment: @sha-1 Your getting it. I wanted to get the `user_id` 4 and 5 so I can able to insert or save this. Unfortunately I'm only getting the first value which is 4.

Answer (score 0):

From your given code it seems you are not using **Eloquent ORM**, you are doing it using **Query Builder**. 
If you don't have a performance concern right now you can do it using separate queries. Like-

```
$departmentRecipient = DB::table('departments')->all();
foreach($departmentRecipient as $department){
$department->users = DB::table('department_user')->where('department_id',$department->id)->pluck('user_id');
}
```

But the better way is to use the eloquent with relationships. Define the many to many relationship in your eloquent model of **Users** and **Departments** (assuming you have eloquent model for them). You will find details about eloquent relationships at [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

**Update:**

From the update of your post it is actually pretty easy to do what you want. If your **Request** contains the selected department id then you can do the following:

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $document = new Document();

    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category;

    $document->save();
    //get the users list of the selected department id
    $selected_department = $request->department_id; //this must be included in your POST data
    $users = DB::table('department_user')->where('department_id',$selected_department)->pluck('user_id');
    //now you have the list of the users id
    foreach($users as $user){
    // do what you need here
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

Following controller code might work for you.

*Controller:*

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    // I am suggesting here to change the '$departmentRecipient' to '$departmentlist', as it is more meaningful. Also in your view
    $departmentlist = DB::table('departments')->get();
    return view ('document.create')->with('departmentlist', $departmentlist);
}
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{
    //same as you have till the $document->save()
    ....
    ....
    //then do this
    $recipients = array();
    $departments = $request->recipient;
    foreach($departments as $department){
        $users = DB::table('department_user')->where('department_id',$department)->pluck('user_id');
        $recipients = array_merge($recipients, $users);
    }
    //now you have a complete list of the users from selected departments
    //Do as you intend to like this
    $user = Auth::user();
    foreach($recipients as $recipientId)
    {
        $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking where I'm gonna put the `foreach` that you given. Should I put it inside post request? I updated my post please see thanks!!

Comment: You don't need the user ids in your view, just only the department id and after the POST request, based on the selected department id, you want to send some documents/information to that department's users. Right?

Comment: I posted my Model so you can have idea. Don't mind the `foreach` that I given. Yes I want to send documents/information to that department's users. Where should I put the `foreach` that you given? Because the error says `Undefined variable: department`

Comment: @Francisunoxx, i have updated my answer. And sorry i had a little mistake on the foreach loop earlier. The array must be before 'as', which i did put after 'as'.

Comment: I reversed your `foreach` to `$departmentRecipient as $department` and try to `dd($department)` and it's getting all the values for "Department of Engineering". I just having a error and can't insert the values. I know I'm already near to my output!

Comment: I'm trying now your output. I'm little bit confuse in `$users = DB::table('department_user')->where('department_id',$selected_department)->pluck('user_id');` Can you see my View and Controller for the last time? Thanks bro.

Comment: In your Form Request, you will get a list of departments in recipient[] array. But what you are doing here: $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false ); 
is not clear to me. Can you explain?

Comment: This will inserted into my junction table. As you can see `$request->recipient` is the name of the select list in my View. I'm already near to my output. I just needed to insert the `$request` from `recipient` form :))

Comment: I think i got it. Just one last clarification. Can you select multiple department (In your select form)?

Comment: You already got it bro! Yes I can select multiple department from select form.

Comment: I get an error it cannot insert or save the department that I selected. `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `sender_id`, `user_id`) values (11, 3, 2))`

Comment: That seems a problem in your 'Document' model. Please check that model and database. Which is out of this questions scope. :)

Comment: I'm still working on it. Can I have a question? What is `users` in `$department->users`?

Comment: From my first code?? I am just adding a dynamic property on each $document object. if you dd() the $departmentRecipient after the loop you will see that there is a 'users' property on each of the $departmentRecipient array element. Hope you got it. Btw, please upvote and/or mark accepted my answer if you found it helpful. Would really appreciate it. :)